# How To manage imageviews and textview with theirs alignments?

Tags: android, layout

**How To manage imageviews and textview with theirs alignments ?**

> here is code i have tried.. i have used toolbar to achieve this but failed to achieve , can anyone tell me how to accomplish this ?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:background="@color/backcolor"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="8">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Grid"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/a"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/a"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/a"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/a"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/a"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[out put i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPUyF.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Instead of using the toolbar you could use a custom layout.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi  can u provide a link or example of custom layout

Comment: create as usual layout instead of toolbar.& <include> where ever u want

Comment: @newpie check my edited answer

Comment: At first create the layout design you want, and use it(like a toolbar) instead of actually using the toolbar

Comment: @newpie Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?attr/fillColor"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textColor="?attr/fillColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="?attr/fillColor" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textColor="?attr/fillColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="?attr/fillColor" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textColor="?attr/fillColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="?attr/fillColor" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textColor="?attr/fillColor"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Here is Screen Shot.**

[image]

Comment: thanks i up voted and also accepted thanks lot and can u please look at this my question i didn't find any solution yet    [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982298/how-to-implement-cascading-in-android-with-image]

Comment: You have not accepted my answer please check again.

Answer (score 1):

Try following layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/com_facebook_button_background_color"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/a"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Grid"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/a"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Grid"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/a"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Grid"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/a"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Grid"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: thanks i up voted and also accepted thanks lot and can u please look at this my question i didn't find any solution yet    [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982298/how-to-implement-cascading-in-android-with-image]

Comment: i did now dear ..and plz look at my second que

Answer (score 1):

Try this way it works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:Fnt_Awsm_Button="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fbutton_color_whight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/marging_pading_8pd">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:background="#f0ff"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/batss"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Grid"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff00ff"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/batss"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Grid"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff00ff"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/batss"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Grid"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff00ff"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/batss"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Grid"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks i up voted and also accepted thanks lot and can u please look at this my question i didn't find any solution yet    [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982298/how-to-implement-cascading-in-android-with-image]

Answer (score 0):

use 4 textview only

```
[<LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/actvity1_padda" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_comp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/chat_secton8"
                android:text="@string/comp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_learn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/lean_businesstip"
                android:text="@string/learn" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_mydoc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/chat_increase"
                android:text="@string/mydoc" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_business"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/chat_secton8"
                android:text="Business" />
        </LinearLayout>][1]
```

Comment: sry didn't get output the i wanted

Comment: use this layout for as a toolbar